# A term for "Groceries, toiletries & Conveniences" everyday products

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, category

Is there a common term that covers both groceries & conveniences. Products that one would purchase either at supermarkets or corner stores?

Is there a venue type that would describe supermarkets, corner stores, bakeries... in one?

This word would not necessarily other shopping products like clothes, electronics, medication, furniture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Groceries* is the term you are looking for. Here in the US, the phrase *grocery shopping* covers every imaginable household consumable. I can go grocery shopping and end up in Walmart, stop at Starbucks or even at a gas station. Oftentimes, grocery shopping is just an excuse to go for a relaxing drive and get some coffee while you're at it!

As for venue, the term *grocery store* is used for supermarkets where fresh produce is often on sale (e.g. Shoprite, StopNShop, Giant). A more general term is *drugstore*. This is used, however, more often to describe convenience stores or "pharmacies". CVS in the US is a great example, as it is rarely referred to as a grocery store.

Comment: Thanks, this covers my need, all other answers are good as well but I found that Groceries will be clearer than staples/sundries to our target market

Answer (score 2):

[staples](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/staples) - A major item of trade in steady demand.

[merchandise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/merchandise) would cover all products.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "commodities" I believe.

Comment: Could you please provide a citation or example for this? I've never heard of *commodities* being used this way, at least in the Northeastern US.

Comment: Commodity or commodities is generic word used to refer to any type of the marketable products.. example: Chocolate is becoming an increasingly expensive food commodity.

Answer (score 1):

Marriam-Webster says of [grocer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grocer):

> a dealer in staple foodstuffs, meats, produce, and dairy products and
>   **usually household supplies**

Tesco refer to themselves a grocer in their literature. So maybe groceries is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "sundries".  May or may not technically cover groceries but I've used it for such with no confusion.